# Prove three statements about the dihedral group $D_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I'm trying to solve this problem from my group theory course:

> Consider the dihedral group $D_6$ of isometries of the euclidean plane
> which fix a regular hexagon:
>
> (a) Prove that this group is generated by the clockwise rotation $x$
> of angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and by the reflection $y$ through two
> opposite vertices.
>
> (b) Show that $x^6=1=y^2$ and $yx=x^{-1}y$.
>
> (c) Show that $D_6=\{x^ny^m:0\leq n<6, 0\leq m<2\}$

I'm having trouble finding good answers for (a) and (c) (the question (b) is very easy to prove). I have the idea in my head, I know that's true, my problem is about finding a "right" way to explain it on paper. I don't know what are the right arguments to prove that statements are true. In fact, I have this problem in general, every time I need to prove some elements generate a certain group. How can I prove this? How can I prove that certain elements generate certain group in general? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If (a) and (b) are true then surely (c) follows at once? To get (a) I'd first prove $x$ and $y$ are in the group. Then there are two sorts of symmetry: those that preserve the sense and those that change it. The sense preserving ones must be powers of $x$ since if the vertices are $P_0,\dots, P_5$ and $g$ maps $P_0$ to $P_i$ then $g$ must map $P_1$ to a vertex distance $1$ from $P_i$, and $P_{i+1}$ is the only candidate, the other choice reverses the sense. If $g$ is sense reversing, $gy$is sense preserving, so as we've jsut seen $gy=x^k$ for some $k$.